# K3 coming from Enriques surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

We know every Enriques surfaces has a K3 surface as its universal cover. My question is: what kind of K3 surface is the double cover of an Enriques surface? Or equivalently, what kind of K3 surface has a fixed point free involution?

In particular, can any quartic K3 be the double cover of an Enriques surface?

Thanks

Comment: Enriques surface, not Enrique.

Comment: The moduli space of Enriques surfaces is 10 dimensional, so there is only a 10-dimensional family of K3's with a free involution. In particular, a general quartic does not admit such. Among quatrics, such are so called "quartic symmetroids". For more details see the book of Cossec-Dolgachev.